# How do I name dataframes in a list in R after the CSV file they came from?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, csv

I have a folder called "Results" with CSV files in it. The naming scheme of them is "Sim_Results_x.csv", where x is the nth simulation. I want to make these into a list of dataframes which are named after the file they were read in from. So for example, I want Sim_Results_1.csv to be called Sim_Results_1 in the list of dataframes, rather than [[1]]. I tried the code below but instead of naming the dataframe after the file, it names the first column after the file, and all other columns are named "NA." How could I fix this?

```
#get list of names of all files in results folder
filenames <- list.files("Results", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
#sort them in numeric order
filenames <- mixedsort(filenames)
#combine into list of dataframes
ldf <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))
  df <- read.csv(x)
  names(df) <- name
  # Return dataframe
  df
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the base R [`setNames()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/setNames) function. The key point is that you are applying the names to the list, rather than to each item in the list.

```r
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv) |>
    setNames(
        tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(filenames))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Map/read.csv and then edit the lists names as shown in the last line.

```
library(tools)
ldf <- Map(read.csv, filenames)
names(ldf) <- file_path_sans_ext(basename(names(ldf))
```